# Multiple ignore-fields for is_unique-function

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-4

I'm having some issues with the Codeigniter 4 validation rules. I'm using the is_unique function within the ruleset in Order to except one single row from the validation.

The problem here is that there are two fields in the table that need to be checked:

```
'episodeTitle' => [
                    'label' => 'episodeTitle',
                    'rules' => 'required|max_length[100]|is_unique[episodes.episodeTitle,episodes.episodeID,' . $episodeID . ',episodes.podcastID,' . $podcastID . ']',
                    'errors' => [
                        'required' => lang('Errors.nested.episode.episodeTitleRequired'),
                        'max_length' => lang('Errors.nested.messages.maxLength100'),
                        'is_unique' => lang('Errors.nested.episode.episodeTitleUnique'),
                    ],
                ],
```

Is it possible, to make the exception depending on 2 or more fields?

I want to check the episodeID AND the podcastID not only one of these values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom rule to achieve what you're looking for.

Rules are stored within simple, namespaced classes. They can be stored any location you would like, as long as the autoloader can find it. These files are called RuleSets. To add a new RuleSet, edit Config/Validation.php and add the new file to the $ruleSets array:

```
public $ruleSets = [
    \CodeIgniter\Validation\Rules::class,
    \CodeIgniter\Validation\FileRules::class,
    \CodeIgniter\Validation\CreditCardRules::class,
];
```

Within the file itself, each method is a rule and must accept a string as the first parameter, and must return a boolean true or false value signifying true if it passed the test or false if it did not:

```
class MyRules
{
    public function check_unique(string $str): bool
    {
        // Your code to check the values and don't forget to return true or false.
    }
}
```

Then in your validation just use the check_unique rule.

Comment: Hey, Yeah that's what i thought. I actually made a cuatom rule and it does work (hooray!) i will share my solution on monday!